# validation for Time HH:MM am or pm Format using regular expression

Tags: asp.net

I am working on web application using asp.net with vb code.

I have a textbox for time field for which i am using regular expression validator.

the format i want is HH:MM am. the regular expression i am using is `"(0[1-9]|[1][0-2])[:]" + "(0[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])[ ][A|a|P|p][M|m]"`

i am entering the time example: 08:30 AM or 08:30 PM but the regular expression is showing error message.

Can anyone help me with correct regular expression.

thankyou all in advance

shubha

Comment: Well your regex could certainly be simplified, but it does match "08:30 AM" - so it's not clear where the problem is.

Answer (score 7):

Use RegularExpressionValidator and below ValidationExpression. I have used that.

```
ValidationExpression="^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\040(AM|am|PM|pm)$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regular expressions, use `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead. I recommend using the regular `TryParse` method because it affords your visitors flexibility in their formats (e.g. some visitors might want to use the 24-hour system, whereas others can use the 12-hour system).

```
String input;
DateTime dt;
if( !DateTime.TryParse( input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture /* change if appropriate */, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt ) ) {
    // show error message
}
```

Now as you're using a validator, you'll want to wrap up this logic in a `Validator` subclass, but it's really easy:

```
public class DateTimeValidator : BaseValidator {

    protected override bool EvaluateIsValid() {

        String controlValidationValue = base.GetControlValidationValue(base.ControlToValidate);
        if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( controlValidationValue ) ) return true;

        DateTime dt;
        return DateTime.TryParse( input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture /* change if appropriate */, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt );
    }
}
```

Then (assuming you've registered a tag-prefix in `web.config`) all you need to do is this:

```
<label>
    Enter a valid date/time value.
    <input type="text" runat="server" id="someDate" />
    <myprefix:DateTimeValidator runat="server" controlToValidate="someDate" />
</label>
```

You will need a separate `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator>` if you want the field to be required.