# Regular Expressions - Datetime

Tags: c#, regex

What's the regular expression for a date time formatted like that :

```
03:12 PM (HH:MM PM)
```

I have a string that encapsulates a date time, I want to have the first occurence of date time in it. I want to use *Regex* class in c# in order to do this. Thank you.

Comment: _"I am using Regex class in c#"_ Ok, then show what you've tried.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615087/validation-for-time-hhmm-am-or-pm-format-using-regular-expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615087/validation-for-time-hhmm-am-or-pm-format-using-regular-expression)

Comment: A [lenient version](http://regex101.com/r/jB9fY8) and a [strict version](http://regex101.com/r/wJ5iO2)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s*[AP]M
```

Which is 1 or 2 digits, followed by a colon, followed by 2 digits, followed by any number of whitespace characters, followed by AM or PM.

Test thoroughly to avoid false positives.

Comment: Thank you that's what I searched for.